# Make this program display an error message if a negative number is entered, and prompt for a new positive number?

Tags: c++

How can I make this program display an error message if a user enters a negative number, and then prompt for a new positive number? Since this is a decimal to hexadecimal calculator the user should not be able to enter a negative number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool play_again;
    do
    {
    int dec_num, r;
    string hexdec_num = "";
    char hex[] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F' };
    cout << "\n\n Convert a decimal number to hexadecimal number:\n";
    cout << "---------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << " Input a decimal number: ";
    cin >> dec_num;

    while (dec_num > 0)
    {
        r = dec_num % 16;
        hexdec_num = hex[r] + hexdec_num;
        dec_num = dec_num / 16;
    }
    cout << " The hexadecimal number is : " << hexdec_num << "\n";
    while (true) // loop asking user
    {
        string user_input;
        cout << "again? ('y', 'n'):" << endl;
        cin >> user_input;

        if (user_input == "y")
        {
            play_again = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (user_input == "n")
        {
            play_again = false;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
        }
    }
    } while (play_again);
}
```

Comment: you can add an `if statement` under the `cin >> dec_num;` to check the value of `dec_num` like that `if (dec_num < 0)` and print an error and ask him if he want to reenter a number again

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by adding an if statement after the `cin >> dec_num;` so you can check its value if it's under the `0` or no

add this line under the line `cin >> dec_num;`:

```
if (dec_num < 0)
{
  //do whatever you want here
}
```